# delimit blocks - openTBS / xlsx, 

Tags: php, xlsx, tinybutstrong, opentbs

im using openTBS to make an excel doc. Here is my problem:

Im trying to replicate submodules under the parent title ( Red one )

[image: code]

and my output is:

[image: output]

is there any way to limit the blocks inside that table? so i can get all the green modules under a large red one? :s

thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

i tried to set an headrgroup to the red one

```
[base_sub.modules;block=c;headergrp=module]
```

but what i got was

[image]

but what i need is a red large one over all the green ones, like a title +/-

**UPDATE:**

my template:

[image]

my output(excel):

[image]

should i use other type of block? instead of `block=c`? any help will be appreciated

Comment: Where is the main block ? Why green sub-block are displayed after the two white ones ?

Comment: i dont know why the greens are displayed after the 2 white ones, that is my question :) i tried to set [base_sub2.modules;block=c;headergrp=module], ill post what i got. and thanks for all your help

Comment: They are several strange points in your template: (a) Your are using `[base;block=begin;...]` but where the block is ending ? Using block=being/block=end with OpenTBS is often dangerous because this can split underlying XML entities. (b) You are using `[base_sub2...;block=c]` twice. Used like this will make block [base_sub2] having two alternating sections. This is probably not what you're expecting.

Comment: i forgot to print here but the `block=end` is right after that table, im gonna try without the double `block=c`.. and one more time, tks for ur help

Comment: if i dont add the `block=c` on `[base_sub2.test]` that dont replicate... and if i add it the result its that one from last image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some advices that may help for your template :

1. Avoid using `block=begin/block=end` by replacing the TBS tag `[base;block=beging;sub1=trainees;sub2=modules]` with `[base;block=row+row+row+row+row;sub1=trainees;sub2=modules]`, and then delete tag `[base;block=end]`. This may not change things for now but this will prevent from further unexpected XML split.
2. Add parameter "p1" without value in the couple of [base_sub2] tags. Like this : `[base_sub2.module;block=c;p1]` and `[base_sub2.test;block=c;p1]`. This will make TBS to use multi-blocks instead of one block with alternating sections.
3. Add a TBS tag `[base_sub2;block=c;p1]` in the red cell "Modulos".
4. Avoid using merged cells that can be moved after the merging (like cells in a block of cells under a block). That is because in Ms Excel, information of merged cells is saved separatlly of cells themselves. So it cannot not be duplicated simply be duplicating cells. Use cells formating instead. For example: use background colors, fore colors, borders for cells "Formados", "Media Final", "Situaciao Final".

**Template example :**

[image: Template]

**Result:**

[image]